# Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Then Show that $|(R/I)| = 1 $ if and only if $R = I$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

(i) Show that $|(R/I)| = 1 $ if and only if $R = I$.

(ii) Show that if $R$ has an identity 1 then (if $I \neq R$) so does $R/I$, and if $R$ is commutative, then so is $R/I$.

I know that the quotient ring of $R$ by $I$ is defined to be $R/I = \{a+I : a\in R\}$. but I am not sure what to do for either part here.

Comment: i) Of course there is only 1 equivalence class iff you create only one equvalence class!!!

Comment: ii) If $1a=a=a1$ ofc $[1][a]=[1a]=[a]=[a1]=[a][1]$. And if ab=ba then $[a][b]=[ab]=[ba]=[b][a]$.

Comment: i) The elements of $R/I$ form a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Definition) of $R$.

Comment: I am still unsure about part (i) is $|R/I|$ the number of elements in $R/I$? and how would i use the fact that $R/I$ partitions $R$?

Comment: If $A$ is some set then $|A|$ is common notation for its cardinality (i.e. its number of elements). The elements of $R/I$ are subsets of $R$ that cover $R$ since $R/I$ is a partition of $R$. If there is only one element in this partition ($|R/I|=1$) then the fact that $R/I$ is a partition of $R$ leads to $R/I=\{R\}$ or equivalently $I=R$.